# Android Using Licensing and/or in-app billing

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm developing an application that will have some features that the user must pay to use. I was planning to use a Lite and Pro version for this, but the release of In-App Billing have got me thinking...

If I use In-app billing is there any need to implement the licensing (http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) policies suggested by Google? Or is it enough to implement the Billing stuff?

The application is available for free, instead some features will be enabled using in-app billing. Hence I don't really care if someone "copies" the application as long as they cannot copy purchased features.

BR,
Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

If both applications will be free, you should implement only In-App Billing. You can read [Billing best practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html) for more information.

Comment: I don't presume the 'Pro' version was going to be free... does that change your advice?  I'm wondering because the in-app billing marketing/PR stuff plainly states that in-app billing should be for extra _content_ and not features.  The link you pointed to didn't clarify at all.

Comment: @Chris There are many applications on the market that have two version - free and paid one. Many of them have only one package, which is free and if you want more features, you have to download a license key from the market. The in-app billing can be used both for extra features and content.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the inapp billing and licensing code don't play well together, crashing the app in certain scenarios, like when attempting a purchase when not online.

I don't think it would be worth the risk and overhead to use licensing for a free app even with inapp purchase options. I believe the licensing documentation even mentions licensing can't be used with free apps.